# Error message: attempt to use zero-length variable name

Tags: message, zero, chunks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNxbz.png)

I don't know what's wrong with my code chunk...
I tried to put `right after but the error message is the same. Should I put another code between these codes? Or am I doing wrong? Is it right to put` at the end of the codes that I want to make it as a chunk?